# Automatically increasing font size in Swing

Tags: java, swing, fonts, layout-manager, look-and-feel

I would like to know if there are methods of automatically increasing the font size based on the size of a component. I have this gui here:
[image]

Hovewer if i increase the size of the frame, it becomes like this:
[image]
the font size doesn't increase. and i don't have an idea on how to make this work.

Comment: Hope this will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989107/change-font-size-of-a-jpanel-and-all-its-elements

Comment: There are multiple ways to increment font size using swing/awt. Could you show us some code?

Answer (score 4):

Some L&Fs support a [`sizeVariant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513) with `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`. Alternatively, you can scale the font to fill the space allocated by your chosen layout, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014525/230513).

[image]